# How to manipulate JWPLAYER with Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, tampermonkey

I've been trying to manipulate a JWPlayer externally, using tampermonkey.

The problem I get is that "JWPlayer" is not Defined.

```js
var player = jwplayer("myVideo");
```

Simply declaring a player as a jwplayer is not possible.
To fix I've been to "import" the jwplayer.js:

```js
// @require      https://vidstreaming.io/js/jw8.9/jwplayer.js
```

Which didn't work...

---

**My objective:** is to to the following through tampermonkey

When I'm at browser, using developer tools I can use

**getPosition()** to get the current playtime of the video

then **seek()** to play from there..

```js
jwplayer().getPosition()
```

```js
jwplayer().seek(X)
```

---

Any idea how to "import" jwpalyer.js into Tampermonkey script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this works for you from dev tools:

```
jwplayer().getPosition()
```

then what you want is to access `window.jwplayer` global variable. If you are not using any GM specific features, all you need is to make sure your script starts after the player is loaded. Eg. this should be late enough:

```
// @run-at      document-idle
```

If you're using some `@grant` privileges, it is still possible, via [unsafe window](https://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) permission:

```
@grant unsafeWindow
```

Then, this is what you run:

```
unsafeWindow.jwplayer().getPosition()
```

Please pay attention to the warning:

> #### This command can open certain security holes in your user script, and it is recommended to use this command sparingly.
>
> #### Please be sure to read the entire article and understand it before using it in a script.

So make sure to read the article and understand not to expose any greasemonkey functions to the outside webpages. **Never** use it with `#include *`.

Comment: I also just find about i can declare **var jwplayer** instead **var player**, but NEED to test before anything, not at home. Thanks for the tips. About security, i am doing this for personal use, since the webpage devs dont implement thenselves a system with "resume from where last stop"... Still 'dangerous' for me? Regards

Comment: @AngeloSilva The danger of unsafeWindow is that if the website gets hacked, some malicious script could exploit a bug in your script to run GM_ functions.

Comment: I was having problems because the actual JWPlayer is inside of iFrame. Thanks for your help. Also window.jwplayer worked like a charm. Should i leave the topic as it is? Once again thanks

Comment: @AngeloSilva Yes, there's no need to change topic of the question. I guess you set the userscript to run in the iframe? Remember that if the question is answered and it works for you, you can mark the answer as accepted. This helps other in finding which questions still need answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// @grant unsafeWindow
// @require      https://urlto/jwplayer.js

;(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     var ownPlayer = jwplayer();
     ownPlayer.on("ready",function(e) {
        console.log(this.getPlaylist());
     });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please expand on your answer and explain what you did and why you did it.

Comment: Hello, I failed in my Objective, but I found that was because the JWPlayer is inside an iFrame. My objective was to make a Button (outside of iFrame) that loads the player where last stopped. For example I was watching an Episode and stoped at 10min, later when Visiting the same page of that episode I could simply click "Continue" button, and JWPlayer would load/change to where I stoped (10min).